# How to convert currency formatted String back to a BigDecimal? (using Java NumberFormat)

Tags: java, android, locale, number-formatting

In my Android app I've got an EditText from which I take a number, and convert that to a BigDecimal, and from there to a local Currency formatting:

```
String s = "100000";
Locale dutch = new Locale("nl", "NL");
NumberFormat numberFormatDutch = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(dutch);
Log.e(this, "Currency Format: "+ numberFormatDutch.format(new BigDecimal(s.toString())));
```

This prints out €100.000,00 like expected. I now however, want to convert this back into a BigDecimal.

Is there a way that I can convert a locally formatted currency string back to a BigDecimal?

Comment: why would you want to do that when you have `s` that is the basic representation of the number ?

Comment: You can strip out all non-numeric characters from a string with regex, e.g. str = str.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )  That doesn't directly answer your question, hence it's just a suggestion of an approach you could take.

Comment: @NigelK - Unfortunately that doesn't take into account that on mainland Europe (including the Netherlands) we use the comma as a decimal mark, where most English speaking countries use the dot as a decimal mark. For this reason that would already fail.

Comment: have you tried to use numberFormatDutch.parse(myString, new ParsePosition(0));

Answer (score 7):

```
    String s = "100000";
    Locale dutch = new Locale("nl", "NL");
    NumberFormat numberFormatDutch = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(dutch);

    String c = numberFormatDutch.format(new BigDecimal(s.toString()));
    System.out.println("Currency Format: "+ c);
    try {
        Number  d = numberFormatDutch.parse(c);
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d.toString());
        System.out.println(bd);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Currency Format: € 100.000,00

100000

Comment: "Is there a way that I can convert a locally formatted currency string back to a BigDecimal?" - Your answer won't give him a BigDecimal instance.

Comment: The fix won't work for fractional amounts. Setting `s` to "3.14" will set `bd` to 3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875.

Comment: yes, you are right because of double implementation on Java, edited

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you don't assign BigDecimal to something so you cant convert it back.

```
//Assign BigDecimal
BigDeciaml x = new BigDecimal(s.toString());
//Your code line
Log.e(this, "Currency Format: "+ numberFormatDutch.format(x));
//x it's the same as before
System.out.println(x);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a better solution, but this is the best I've come across so far. It relies on the fact that NumberFromat.getCurrencyInstance returns a DecimalFormat. I don't like having to cast it, but the setParseBigDecimal will cause the parse method to return a BigDecimal instead of a number. And yet another cast on parse. I'm using US locale, but it's easy to change to NL

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat)fmt).setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal amount = (BigDecimal)fmt.parse("$1,000,000.00");
System.out.println(amount.toString());
```